# scaling mesh and armature

Tags: armature, bones

Okay, so I've downloaded a mesh from a website for practice and the mesh itself has an armature. Now I want to know if I were to scale a certain part of the mesh's body to make it be taller, like the arms or legs, will it affect the armature bones in any way? Will the bones have to be adjusted to fit the mesh's body? or will the bones scale along with what ever part of the mesh is being scaled?

I will appreciate any advice thanks.

Comment: it should work but just try it on a copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bone wouldn't follow your modifications in edit-mode (unless maybe with specific constraints, which you would have to set manually).

So the bone would have to be manually adjusted (in edit-mode, not pose-mode) to follow.

Another approach would be to modify (scale for example) your bone in pose-mode. The associated parts of the mesh would follow the bone (if your vertex groups/bones associations are set up properly).

It's not easy to give you an "advice" because we don't really know what you want to do. You're only asking "If I do A, does it imply B ?". So answers are limited to yes/no.

For an advice, you should probably directly ask something like "In the context C, what are my options for doing D ?". Here we have part of C, but no real idea about D.

Comment: That solution doesn't work lately. The scaled object is considered a "pose". And so you can't apply the scale to it without jumbling the pieces. And if you try to set the new scaled object as the reset pose, it also jumbles the objects. Maybe Blender changed it. I've been all over, and so far no one has a simple way to just scale the bones and mesh the same, and end up being able to apply the scale so all are 1 when you are done.